# How can I split a large number to 3 groups of numbers using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I have a serial like this `12k4353535352311` and I want to make it like below using JavaScript:

```
12k4-35353535-2311
```

I have tried this, but I think it's useless

```
$('#dev_serial').change(function(){
   //var serial = $('#dev_serial').val();
   var number =$('#dev_serial').val();
    output = [],
    sNumber = number.toString();
     alert(output);

/* Outputs:
 *
 * [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7]
 */ 
   //var series = (''+serial)[1]; 
});
```

Comment: Try `str.replace(/(\w{4})(\d{8})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3);`. Check [regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kM0lD8/1). For explanation check top right corner.

Comment: can you explain it to me ?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/uS3eP6/1 + [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
var key = "12k4353535352311";
var res = key.substring(0,4)+'-'+key.substring(4,12)+'-'+key.substring(12,16); //This contains 12k4-35353535-2311
</script>
```